# What would be the best way of solving this integration $\int \frac{3}{5x+2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the integral
>
> $$\int \dfrac{3}{5x+2}dx$$

I've been looking for a strategy in such a way as to solve the integrals faster and easier. However, there was nothing useful. Thereby, I wanted to ask my question on Math.SE. Does there exits any strategy?

Comment: it would be very helpful to see the context of the problem (is it a homework assignment) and some effort fo your own to solve it...

Comment: @gt6989b That wasn't actually homework problem. I'm just asking whether or there's any strategy.  I highly demand you to take a look at the question correctly.

Comment: Cargobob: No matter; don't ask users on this site to do your work for you, unless you're willing to bring your efforts and thoughts to the post of your questions.

Comment: Strategy in this case: use substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int \frac{f'}{f}=\log(f)$$
What's the derivative of your denominator?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Make a substitution $u=5x+2$ to end up with a flavor of $\int du/u$.

Comment: Can I apply  substitution on whole integrations?

Comment: @Cargobob yes, why not?

Comment: In fact, failure to apply a substitution to *all* of the integrand, the differential and the limits is the most common error in integration by substitution...

Answer (score 0):

Simply

$$I=\int \dfrac{3}{5x+2}dx=\frac 35\int \dfrac{dx}{x+2/5}$$